# Regex to match only few letters and numbers

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex that matches letters ('R', 'L'), numbers and first character is always letter.
E.G.

```
I want regex to accept string like "R12L", "L1" that start with either 'R' or 'L' only.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to match words that:

- Start with any letter
- contain numbers, 'R' and 'L'

Here is: `\b[a-zA-Z][0-9RL]*\b`

In case the first letter must be either 'R' or 'L', then this will be better:

```
`\b[RL][0-9RL]*\b`
```

Explanation:

- `\b` is a word boundary, a zero length match
- `[RL]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), it matches either R or L
- `[0-9]` is a range within the character class, it matches anything between 0 and 9.

You can play with [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/nSiqb6/1).

Comment: thank you. I did few changes $regex = "/\b[RL][0-9RL]*\b/"; then worked perfectly. Thankx